# Isomorphism of transcendental extensions

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

If $a,b$ are transcendental over $\mathbb{Q}$, then it is known that $\mathbb{Q}(a)$ and $\mathbb{Q}(b)$ are isomorphic.

Consider a simple case: suppose $a,b,c$ are transcedental over $\mathbb{Q}$. Assume that $b\notin \mathbb{Q}(a)$ and $a\notin\mathbb{Q}(b)$. Consider than the extension $\mathbb{Q}(a,b)$. Can it be isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}(c)$?

Note that I have put weaker condition on $a,b$; if $a,b$ are algebraically independent, then this is obvious that $b\notin \mathbb{Q}(a)$ and $a\notin\mathbb{Q}(b)$.

Comment: I think something like $\pi^2$ and $\pi^2 + \pi$ works.

Comment: Possibly related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1895398